# How to access array inside the closure of a function?

Tags: javascript

How do I access the array at B? I have tried to console.log .circle["[[Scopes]]"]["0"].B but it says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

[image]

Comment: Try `circle.Scopes[0].B`

Comment: Not at all. `[[Scopes]]` is an internal property of a closure. You cannot access it. Show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

`circle` appears to be a function, and what you're looking at there appears to be debug information about the functions prototype.

I don't think you'll be able to get access to those values at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

That is showing you debug information about the closures that are available to the function. If you are writing code which is inside the `circle` function, then you can just type `B` to interact with that variable. But if you are outside of the circle function, you have no way to access its closures.